# How to test inviting friends on Facebook app without submitting your app

Tags: facebook

I create a Facebook app that would invite your friends based on their network (college, high school, professional workplace etc). However, I don't want my friends to see the invitations to an app still in development until I submit the app (adding the logo, image, description etc).

Furthermore, I want to be able to test the ability to send more than 50 people, ie, send the first 50, mark them as "sent", send the next batch of 50, etc.

So my question is, how do you test that functionality?

My hypothesis is I could create up to 500 test users and make them all friends with each other. So I could probably test that way.

However, what about people on my team that want to try out that feature with their own (real) accounts? How could you test with a real user's account and not spam your friends before the app is submitted to the App Center?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well did you try enabling Sandbox mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis is true. This is the way I do it.

You can make as much users as you need... make them friend of each others and try to test with it.
You can set up the credentials (user name / password) of the test users, so you can login in facebook in the machine you like.  If you like someone else do the test give it the credentials.